# How can I add an extra cell to the end of my table?

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have a table of students and their grades. I want to add a field that allows the user to add a new assignment and grade for the last column. I have

```
echo "<td><div contenteditable='true' placeholder='".$row2['Student Name']."'></div></td>";
```

to put in the last column, but just adding it in my last cell created an off by one error as shown 
[image: in this picture (follow the link I can't embed photos yet).]

My code is as follows

```
$last_stud = null;

    while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        if($last_stud != $row2['Student Name']){

            // close previous <tr>
            if ( $last_stud !== null ) {
                echo "<td><div contenteditable='true' placeholder='".$row2['Student Name']."'></div></td>";
                echo '</tr>';
            }

            $last_stud = $row2['Student Name'];
            echo"<tr><td>{$row2['Student Name']}</td>";
            echo"<td>{$row2['grade']}</td>";
        } else {
            echo"<td>{$row2['grade']}</td>";
        }
    }
    echo '</tr>';
```

How can I change this code to correct my off by one error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `$last_stud` not `$row2['Student Name']`, as you want the previous student, not the current student.

```
echo "<td><div contenteditable='true' placeholder='".$last_stud."'></div></td>";
```

For the last student, you will also need to include it **after** the loop as well -

```
}
echo "<td><div contenteditable='true' placeholder='".$last_stud."'></div></td>";
echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: Thanks! But including it after the loop makes it appear in the first column every time so I'll still have to find a way to add the last one